# How to use inline scripting in chrome extension development manifest v3 with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, frontend, content-security-policy

So, I am developing a chrome extension, and it keeps saying that chrome refuses to execute inline-script. I searched and tried the followings:

1. Break up the Javascript section into a separate file, but it does not work.
2. Change manifest.json to content_security_policy, I searched a lot, but all of the answers are in manifest v2, not v3.
3. I used  tag, but it doesn't work as well.

Here is my code:
main.html

```html
<body>
    <script src="../vue/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="../axios.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/left.css">
    <div class="title">
        <div id="title">{{ date.year }}年{{ date.month }}月{{ date.day }}日</div>
        <div id="subTitle">星期{{ date.weekday }}</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="weather">
        {{currentLocation}} &nbsp; {{ currentWeather }} &nbsp; {{ currentTemperature }}℃
    </div>
    <script type="module" nonce="rAnd0m">
        const { createApp, ref, reactive, onMounted } = Vue
        const time = createApp({
            setup(){
                // Title
                var d = new Date()
                const date = reactive({
                    year: d.getFullYear(),
                    month: d.getMonth(),
                    day: d.getDay(),
                    weekday: d.getDay()
                })
                // 判断 因为weekday传回的是数字
                switch(date.weekday){
                    case 0: date.weekday = "天"
                    case 1: date.weekday = "一"
                    case 2: date.weekday = "二"
                    case 3: date.weekday = "三"
                    case 4: date.weekday = "四"
                    case 5: date.weekday = "五"
                    case 6: date.weekday = "六"
                }
                
                return {
                    // Title
                    date
                }
            }
        }).mount('.title')
        const weather = createApp({
            setup(){
                let currentWeather = ref()
                let currentLocation = ref()
                let currentTemperature = ref()
                onMounted(() => {
                    axios.get('http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=(key deleted)&q=Singapore&aqi=no&lang=zh')
                    .then((response)=>{
                        currentWeather.value = response.data.current.condition.text
                        currentLocation.value = response.data.location.name
                        currentTemperature.value = response.data.current.temp_c
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                })
                return {
                    currentWeather,
                    currentLocation,
                    currentTemperature
                }
            },
        }).mount('#weather')
    </script>
</body>
```

manifest.json

````json
{
    "name": "Handy New Tab",
    "description": "New Tab",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "/images/icon16.png",
        "48": "/images/icon48.png",
        "128": "/images/icon128.png"
      }
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "/scripts/temp.html"
    },
    "background": {
      "vue": "/vue/dist/vue.global.js"
    }
}```
````

Comment: I believe you have to whitelist the domain in the manifest file.

Something like

`"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.somescript.com/*"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
]
`